# Preferred way to model nullable TIMESTAMP with a Gorm model?

Tags: go, go-gorm, code-readability

I'm implementing a Gorm model to access a table in MySQL.
It is something like this:

```golang
import (
    "time"
)

type MyModel struct {

  // ...some attributes...

  CreatedAt time.Time
  UpdatedAt time.Time
  DeletedAt *time.Time
}
```

I am wondering if it is clear enough to follow Gorm [conventions](https://gorm.io/docs/conventions.html#gorm-Model) about using a pointer to `time.Time` to point (;)) out this attribute could be `nil`, or it is better to use [database/sql/NullTime](https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#NullTime).

Do you think of any other benefit to use NullTime apart from readability?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With NullTime you do not need to do nil checks everywhere to avoid panic.

Also, some other db libraries use null conversion wrappers: [sqlboiler](https://github.com/volatiletech/sqlboiler#requirements), [dbr](https://github.com/gocraft/dbr/blob/86d103b35f48d98f4ce3744ec10113da2fc6e737/types.go#L31), [sqlc](https://github.com/kyleconroy/sqlc/blob/4ea3e2764ed4ba4b5dd4b848db1a161eee308e87/docs/time.md), and db-related services in the [AWS sdk](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/api/aws/#pkg-overview)